# New line string from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I cant do new line from javascript, I tried to do that with \n, but nothing.

```js
document.getElementById("text").textContent =  "hhh" + '\n' + "df";
```

```html
<h1 id="text">
  abc
</h1>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you are pretty new in javascript. You should use `<br>` instead. `\n` new line for console outputs. Also you should use `innerHTML` instead of `textContent`.

```js
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML =  "hhh" + '<br>' + "df";
```

```html
<h1 id="text">
  abc
</h1>
```

With `textContent`

```js
document.getElementById("text").textContent =  "hhh" + '<br>' + "df";
```

```html
<h1 id="text">
  abc
</h1>
```

Console example:

```js
console.log("abc\ndef");
```

Answer (score 3):

Changing `textContent` to `innerText` will do it.

```js
document.getElementById("text").innerText =  "hhh" + '\n' + "df";
```

```html
<h1 id="text">
  abc
</h1>
```

The line break behavior [is standardized](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-innertext-idl-attribute).

Comment: interesting. I saw it for the first time.

Comment: Very useful difference vs. `textContent`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think ( I cant remember) that there was another difference maybe with inner tags that are being displayed when you ask for innerText , while not displayed in the other method...but I think it might not relates to this ^.

Comment: I know there are several differences. I rarely remember what they are, but this treatment of newlines is a major useful one... :-)